# python - error in tkinter.py line 1470; lambda takes exactly 1; 0 given. when trying to load window

Tags: python, python-2.7, datagrid, lambda, tkinter

I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

When i call this class

```
class settingsWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, settings):
        self.master = master

        self.titleLb = tk.Label(self.master, text='MesterMind', font=('Calibri', 22))
        self.titleLb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W', columnspan=2)

        self.subTitleLb = tk.Label(self.master, text="Settings", font=('Calibri', 18))
        self.subTitleLb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W', columnspan=2)
```

Using this to create instance of the class

```
def settings(self):
    self.settingsWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = settingsWindow(self.settingsWindow, self.settings)
```

I have no idea what has caused the error and i don't see any obvious errors in the code.
I am using python 2.7

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

edit: NB, tk is the Tkinter module

edit here is the entire python module, (MasterMind.py). i think all the relevent parts are above.

```
'''
Created on 9 Nov 2013

@author: SB960
'''

import Tkinter as tk

def settingsArgs():
    '''
    stores the settings for the game.
    no param = get value
    param = assign value | returns true if value assigned, false otherwise.
    everything stored here is a constant for the duration of the game
    '''
    prefDic = {'COLOURS': 3,
               'PEGS': 3,
               'ROWS': 3,
               'PLAYER1': 'COMPUTER',
               'PLAYER2': 'COMPUTER'} #Dictionary containing preference values

    def colours(int1 = 0):
        if int1 == 0:
            return prefDic['COLOURS']
        elif 3 <= int1 <= 8:
            prefDic['COLOURS'] = int1
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def pegs(int1 = 0):
        if int1 == 0:
            return prefDic['PEGS']
        elif 3 <= int1 <= 8:
            prefDic['PEGS'] = int1
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def rows(int1 = 0):
        if int1 == 0:
            return prefDic['ROWS']
        elif 3 <= int1 <= 12:
            prefDic['ROWS'] = int1
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def player1(string1 = ''):
        if string1.isalnum():
            prefDic['PLAYER1'] = string1
            return True
        elif string1 == '':
            return prefDic['PLAYER1']
        else:
            return False

    def player2(string1 = ''):
        if string1.isalnum():
            prefDic['PLAYER2'] = string1
            return True
        elif string1 == '':
            return prefDic['PLAYER2']
        else:
            return False

    def copy(settings):
        colours(settings('colours')())
        pegs(settings('pegs')())
        rows(settings('rows')())
        player1(settings('player1')())
        player2(settings('player2')())

    def importFromFile(fileName = 'SETTINGS'):
        '''
        imports saved settings from fileName. see exprtTofile
        '''
        try:
            f = open(fileName, 'r')
        except:
            return False
        header = f.readline().strip()
        if header == 'MASTERMINDSETTINGS':
            settingsStr = f.readline().strip()
            settingsLs = settingsStr.split('/')
            for i in range(0, len(settingsLs), 2):
                prefDic[settingsLs[i]] = int(settingsLs[i+1])

            settingsStr = f.readline().strip()
            settingsLs = settingsStr.split('/')
            for i in range(0, len(settingsLs), 2):
                prefDic[settingsLs[i]] = str(settingsLs[i+1])

        f.close()  

    def exportToFile(fileName = 'SETTINGS'):
        '''
        exports current settings to file
        stored of form:
        MASTERMINDSETTINGS
        attribute1/decimal1/attribute2/decimal2/...
        attribute1/string1/...
        '''
        f = open(fileName, 'w')
        f.write('MASTERMINDSETTINGS')
        f.write('COLOURS', prefDic['COLOURS'], 'PEGS', prefDic['PEGS'], 'ROWS', prefDic['ROWS'], sep = '/' )
        f.write('PLAYER1', prefDic['PLAYER1'], 'PLAYER2', prefDic['PLAYER2'])
        f.close()


    return (lambda op: {'COLOURS': colours,
                        'PEGS': pegs,
                        'ROWS': rows,
                        'PLAYER1': player1,
                        'PLAYER2': player2,
                        'COPY': copy,
                        'IMPORT': importFromFile}[op.upper()])

def boardArgs():
    '''
    Stores ongoing data about the current game
    '''
    data = {'ROW': 0,
            'POINTS': 0,#the points of player1; see points function
            'CODE': [], #colours stored as a list of ints, 0 = no colour, 1 <= x <= colours is id for colour.
            'BOARD': [], #^ditto except nested list for each row
            'FEEDBACK': [] #^ditto except 0 <= x <= 2
            }

    #get data functions:


    def currentRow():
        return data['ROW']

    def points(player = 1):#player = 1 or 2
        if player == 1:
            return data['POINTS']
        elif player == 2:
            return ((data['ROUND'] - 1) - data['POINTS'])
        else:
            return 0

    def code():
        return data['CODE']

    def board(row, peg):
        row -= 1 #as in list i starts at 0
        peg -= 1 #^ditto
        try:
            return data['BOARD'][row][peg]
        except:
            return 0

    def feedback(row, peg):
        row -= 1 #as in list i starts at 0
        peg -= 1 #^ditto
        try:
            return data['FEEDBACK'][row][peg]
        except:
            return 0

    #assign data functions:

    def newGame(settings): #sets dimensions of boards and initial values
        data['CODE'] = [0] * settings('PEGS')()
        data['BOARD'] = [data['CODE']] * settings('rows')() 
        data['FEEDBACK'] = [data['CODE']] * (1 + settings('rows')()) 
        data['ROW'] = 0
        data['POINTS'] = 0


    def makeMove(code1Ls, settings):
        code2Ls = data['CODE'][:]#creates duplicate of code
        feedback = []#creates feedback list
        del feedback[0]#empties feedback list

        #compare for colour AND position: remove when found
        for i in range(len(code2Ls)):
            if code1Ls[i] == code2Ls[i]:
                feedback.append(2)
                del code1Ls[i]
                del code2Ls[i]

        #compare for colour: remove from code2 only as element of code1 will not be checked thereafter
        for x in code1Ls:
            for i in range(len(code2Ls)):
                if x == code2Ls[i]:
                    feedback.append(1)
                    del code2Ls[i]

        #ensure feedback is congruent to elements of data[feedback]:
        while len(feedback) < settings('PEGS'): feedback.append(0)

        #assign values:
        data['FEEDBACK'][data['ROW']] = feedback
        data['ROW'] += 1

    return (lambda x: {'ROW': currentRow,
                       'POINTS': points,
                       'CODE': code,
                       'BOARD': board,
                       'FEEDBACK': feedback,
                       'NEWGAME': newGame,
                       'MAKEMOVE': makeMove}[x.upper()])



def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = mainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


class mainWindow:


    def __init__(self, master):

        self.settings = settingsArgs()
        self.settings('import')()

        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.geometry('+400+200')
        self.master.title('MasterMind')


        self.title = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'MasterMind', font = ('Calibri', 22))
        self.title.pack()

        self.newGameBtn = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'New Game', width = 25, command = self.newGame)
        self.newGameBtn.pack()

        self.loadGameBtn = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Load Game', width = 25, command = self.loadGame)
        self.loadGameBtn.pack()

        self.settingsBtn = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Settings', width = 25, command = self.settings)
        self.settingsBtn.pack()


        self.frame.pack()
    def newGame(self):
        self.gameWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = gameWindow(self.gameWindow, self.settings)

    def loadGame(self):
        pass

    def settings(self):
        self.settingsWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = settingsWindow(self.settingsWindow, self.settings)

class gameWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, settings):
        self.master = master
        self.settings = settingsArgs()
        self.settings('copy')(settings)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class settingsWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, settings):
        self.master = master

        self.titleLb = tk.Label(self.master, text='MesterMind', font=('Calibri', 22))
        self.titleLb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W', columnspan=2)

        self.subTitleLb = tk.Label(self.master, text="Settings", font=('Calibri', 18))
        self.subTitleLb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W', columnspan=2)




main()
```

Comment: Is that the entire traceback?

Comment: Is this the entire codebase? There are no lambdas here.

Comment: That is the entire traceback. but not the entire codebase. although the code is in MasterMind.py and the error occurs in tkinter.py which is imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mainwindow` class you have two things with the same name `self.settings`

first: `self.settings = settingsArgs()`

second: `def settings(self):`

Change function name in two place for example to `newsettings`

`def newsetting(self):`

and

`self.settingsBtn = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Settings', width = 25, command = self.newsetting)`